# Adding event to svg elements in Phaser3

Tags: svg, phaser-framework

I have one SVG image file, having some paths. Something like:

```
<svg>

  <g>

   <path id="land" class="land" d="M108.114,402.043l0.683,1.604l-1.204.(truncated)">

   <path id="ice" class="ice" d="M288.114,402.541l0.683,1.604l-1.204...........">

   <path id="water" class="water" d="M038.114,402.543l0.683,1.604l-1.204........">

  </g>

</svg>
```

I need to know which path was clicked. When I load SVG image file in Phaser using load.svg(), the event is triggered for the entire image and not just for the area (or path).

So, how can I detect which path was clicked? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be using the wrong terms, but the SVG loader paints the projected SVG to a static bitmap texture. This eliminates the existence of these pathed objects. Even if you split these paths into their own SVG and layer them, the hitboxes for textures is going to be rectangular, based on the size of the texture.

If you separate these paths into their own SVGs, a more computationally expensive hitbox exists, with pixel-perfect enabled for the hitbox setup [Docs Phaser3 #makePixelPerfect](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Input.InputPlugin.html#makePixelPerfect__anchor). This will look at the projected texture and apply a hitboxArea over the pixels that each SVG renders.

A less expensive hitbox for each SVG would be to implement a custom hit test function when the input manager tests for pointer-events. [Docs Phaser3 HitAreaCallback](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.Input.html#.HitAreaCallback__anchor). This is going to be more difficult, and its difficulty depends on the shape of the hitbox you are going for, and how accurate you need this hitbox to be. Basic geometries and contains methods for hit tests can be found in Phaser.Geom namespace, if those don't match your use case you would need to write/find a function yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I had lost hope for getting any help. Splitting the paths to their own SVG sounds good. I will dig into HitAreaCallback.

Comment: BTW what is your opinion on  using Phaser's graphics.fillPoints() instead of SVG path. With fillpoints I could have reference to each area I draw. Only big problem is fillpoints() expects arguments to be an array of Geom.Point and SVGs path attribute is in  totally different format (d="M238.114,402.543l).

Comment: Personally, I would leave the textures as SVGs. I guess it depends on what you expect to do with the textures. If they're static there's no reason to anything other than SVGs.